# Term translation in views

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

i try to create a multilingual page with drupal.

http://alarabi.biz/category-listing

I created some categoreis and translated them with the Internationalization plugin and i18nviews.

So I can chouse the language in views settings

[image]

but all I get is language "und" I think it means undefined.

How to fix it? Terms are translated.

Comment: Did you not translate terms?

Comment: yes, I use the  Internationalization > Taxonomy translation module to translate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Name (Translated) handler provided by i18nviews.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the language settings for the View on the edit page under:

Advanced > Other > Field Language

Comment: this setting has no effect for me